# Driving a WQHD (2560x1440) Viewsonic monitor with Ubuntu - what is needed?

Tags: graphics, resolution, monitor

I just got a Viewsonic VP2770 monitor. Its maximal resolution for either DVI or Display Port is 2560x1440, and I'd like to set that. However, my current laptop is old, and doesn't have neither DVI nor DP (I'm using it right now with a D-Sub connector at 2048x1152).

Since I plan to buy a new machine anyway, I wanted to ask what would be needed to be able to drive such a monitor for sure. What kind of graphics card? Will Intel's integrated graphics do? Should I buy a NVidia card? If so, which? I have no need of fancy graphics / 3D - but I do use the screen real estate.

As for Ubuntu version, is 12.04 good enough (this is what I'm using on my boxes currently) or should I upgrade further to 13.10, etc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, my new machine has a Haswell-class i7 with 4th gen Intel Integrated Graphics:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

I got a motherboard with Display Port support and it works successfully with the monitor - driving it to a beautiful 2560x1440 resolution from Ubuntu 13.10